# Focus On each text input Doesn't work here

Tags: jquery, html, css

First of all please visit this fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/asif097/z6zsc](http://jsfiddle.net/z6zsc)

What I wish for, is this jquery code will run individually for every text input with the class. At this moment this code is running over both text input field at once.

Here is My Jquery code:

```
$(".first-name-input").after("<div class='first-name-input-value'>First Name</div>");

    $(".first-name-input").focus(function(){
        $(".first-name-input-value").hide();
    });

    $(".first-name-input").blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(".first-name-input-value").show();
        }

    });

    $(".first-name-input-value").click(function(){
        $(".first-name-input").focus();
    });
```

I also tried this one: http://jsfiddle.net/z6zsc/1

But didn't succeed. How to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: why not you try `placeholder attribute`? it works fine and solve your problem without `javascript`

Comment: Yes, But what if I need to change any css or the text? therefore `placeholder` is not supported in old browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think probably may want to look at the HTML5 [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) attribute.

http://jsfiddle.net/NWLes/

```
<input type="text" class="first-name-input" placeholder="First Name" required="required"/>
```

or fix your code:- http://jsfiddle.net/vYtmC/

```
$(".first-name-input").after("<div class='first-name-input-value'>First Name</div>");
    $(".first-name-input").focus(function(){
        $(this).next().hide();
    });
    $(".first-name-input").blur(function(){
        if($(this).val() == ""){
            $(this).next().show();
        }

    });
    $(".first-name-input-value").click(function(){
         $(this).prev().focus();
    });
```

Comment: ok. But have a look at the support for placeholder attribute. It is not supported in older browsers.

Comment: At this moment I will use only the second solution you gave me. Browser support is compulsory for me. Thanks again, for mentioning.

Answer (score 1):

In your event handlers, you need to refer to `$(this)` so the handler operates only on the object that triggered the event rather than operating on all the objects.

Since you're trying to operate on another neighboring element, you will need to find that other element relate to the `this` element.

Since the `.first-name-input-value` object is right after the `first-name-input` object, you could use this:

```
$(".first-name-input").focus(function(){
    $(this).next().hide();
});
```

---

FYI, since you're essentially trying to implement HTML5 placeholder functionality, you could also just get a pre-written shim for HTML5 placeholders and use that.  This problem has been solved many times already.  You don't have to reinvent it.  I'm sure the right Google search will find you several prewritten options.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use inline javascript for your input elements,. Which you could also break into a separate function call...

Your updated html would be something like this:

```
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text" size="25" placeholder="First Name"
            onfocus="if (this.value == 'First') { this.value = ''; this.style.color = '#000000'; } " 
            onblur="if (this.value == '') { this.value = 'First'; this.style.color = '#909090'; } " 
            value="First"/>
```

This will achieve the effect you are going for, and can be used individually per input...

Here is an updated fiddle- http://jsfiddle.net/z6zsc/8/

Comment: But, this will also clear the text (value) the user is going to input.